# How to upgrade Atom Editor on Linux?

Tags: atom-editor

What is the best way to upgrade atom on Linux Ubuntu ?
I install atom using official doc

```
  git clone https://github.com/atom/atom
  cd atom
  script/build
  sudo script/grunt install
```

Comment: Just `wget https://atom.io/download/deb -O /tmp/atom.deb && sudo dpkg -i /tmp/atom.deb`.

Comment: Since Atom is dead now, you may eventually want to upgrade to its fork, [Pulsar](https://pulsar-edit.dev/). Thankfully, they support AppImage. So you can always have the latest version by merely downloading the latest AppImage and running it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Now, it looks like the easiest way is to download the new packaged version (.deb or .rpm) from the official releases and install it over your previous one: https://github.com/atom/atom/releases

Comment: This is what I have been doing to update the editor to new versions. Just went from 1.18 to 1.20 today in Ubuntu 16.04 and it kept my settings and my many open projects and tabs.

Comment: You can get official Red Hat and Debian repositories from https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux

Answer (score 61):

I created the following script to update my atom on Ubuntu 14.10.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Update atom from downloaded deb file
rm -f /tmp/atom.deb
curl -L https://atom.io/download/deb > /tmp/atom.deb
dpkg --install /tmp/atom.deb 

echo "***** apm upgrade - to ensure we update all apm packages *****"
apm upgrade --confirm false

exit 0
```

The file atom_update is executable and needs to be called using su:

```
sudo ./atom_update
```

The above works, but nowadays I use the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt -y update
sudo apt -y install atom
apm install \
file-icons \
tabs-to-spaces \
trailing-spaces \
xml-formatter
```

With the above setup

```
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

will update an installed atom to the latest version. The ppa is generally up to date.

Comment: I would remove the `apm upgrade` from this script as it will run that as sudo and you may have issues upgrading packages from within atom in the future.

Comment: I'd also remove atom - you don't want to be running as root.

Comment: But dpkg need to be run as root, isn't it ?

Comment: Removed "atom" from script. Ali W is correct that one should not run this as root. "dpkg" needs to be run as root.

Comment: atom now has an official repo, which has a more up to date version https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2956#issuecomment-353225330

Answer (score 33):

It's now even easier with the APT package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt update
sudo apt install atom
```

And now you can upgrade / dist-upgrade as usual

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: if you don't want to upgrade your whole system, you can run `sudo apt install atom` again and it will update that package only.

Comment: @IamMashed - it should just upgrade it -

The following packages will be upgraded:
  atom

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04: ``atom is already the newest version (1.26.1-1~webupd8~0).`` when the latest stable is ``1.29.0`` (as of now). The ``dpkg --install /tmp/atom.deb`` in the other answer worked.

Comment: and its just broken with 19.10

Answer (score 30):

Current official documentation seem to recommend another method:

[Atom Github Page](https://github.com/atom/atom)

> **Debian** Linux (Ubuntu)
>
> Atom is only available for 64-bit Linux systems.
>
> 1. Download atom-amd64.deb from the Atom releases page.
> 2. Run sudo dpkg --install atom-amd64.deb on the downloaded package.
> 3. Launch Atom using the installed atom command.
>
> The Linux version does not currently
>   automatically update so you will need to repeat these steps to upgrade
>   to future releases.
>
> **Red Hat** Linux (Fedora 21 and under, CentOS, Red Hat)
>
> Atom is only available for 64-bit Linux systems.
>
> 1. Download atom.x86_64.rpm from the Atom releases page.
> 2. Run sudo yum localinstall atom.x86_64.rpm on the downloaded package.
> 3. Launch Atom using the installed atom command.
>
> The Linux version does not currently
>   automatically update so you will need to repeat these steps to upgrade
>   to future releases.
>
> **Fedora** 22+
>
> Atom is only available for 64-bit Linux systems.
>
> 1. Download atom.x86_64.rpm from the Atom releases page.
> 2. Run sudo dnf install ./atom.x86_64.rpm on the downloaded package.
> 3. Launch Atom using the installed atom command.
>
> The Linux version does not currently
>   automatically update so you will need to repeat these steps to upgrade
>   to future releases.

Answer (score 25):

As of this writing, the best option to upgrade to the latest released version of Atom is to check out the most recent tag and build it, especially if you built it in the first place.

1. `cd atom`
2. `git pull`
3. `git checkout v0.115.0` (or whatever the latest release is: https://github.com/atom/atom/releases)
4. `script/build`
5. `sudo script/grunt install`

Answer (score 6):

```
  wget https://atom.io/download/deb -O atom64.deb
  sudo dpkg --install atom64.deb
```

or

```
  wget https://atom.io/download/rpm -O atom64.rpm
  sudo dnf install atom64.rpm
```

the above URLs redirect to `https://atom-installer.github.com/`

Answer (score 4):

An easier way is to install the atom-updater-linux from the packages on the atom website.

Go to edit > preferences > install and search for atom-updater-linux

or from the terminal:

```
apm install atom-updater-linux
```

This should check for updates after every launch and prompt you to install new updates.

Comment: [This package is deprecated](https://atom.io/packages/atom-updater-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Currently the preferred procedure is described at the atom pages [Installing Atom - Platform-linux](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux)

When using the `add-apt-repository` suggested in the top answer, this URL is suggested.

The apt repository mentioned at the Atom pages:

```
curl -sL https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are onn **Ubuntu** you can go to the **Ubuntu Software Center**, search for *Atom* and just click on *Update*. Then job  done!

Comment: Download the latest version from https://atom.io/beta and double click it. Upgrade it using **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is interested, I wrote a [small atom package](https://atom.io/packages/geiger) for this purpose.

The package is meant to timely inform the user of new versions being available (stable or beta, configurable via settings) and uses GitHub API under the hood.  It is platform independent, so it should work with any linux distro, but also with Windows or other systems.

It does *not* perform the upgrade automatically as I wrote it for my needs and I was not interested in such feature.  I may add it in the future should strong interest for it manifest itself, though.

Feedback is welcome, best as [tickets on github](https://github.com/quasipedia/geiger/issues).

Answer (score 2):

### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

Run these commands to quickly and easily install and upgrade the Atom text editor snap package from the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 and later (64-bit only).

- Install Atom text editor:

  ```
    sudo snap install --classic atom
  ```

  Note that a snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Atom extension packages are installed into the user's home directory.
- Upgrade Atom text editor:

  ```
    sudo snap refresh --classic atom
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded from

`Atom    : 1.26.1
Electron: 1.7.11
Chrome  : 58.0.3029.110
Node    : 7.9.0`

to

`Atom    : 1.40.1
Electron: 3.1.10
Chrome  : 66.0.3359.181
Node    : 10.2.0`

I followed these simple steps,

1. create a file

`sudo nano /usr/local/bin/atom-update`

2. copy following snippet and save with Ctrl+o and "enter" and Ctrl+x

your code

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/latest -O /tmp/latest
wget --progress=bar -q 'https://github.com'$(cat /tmp/latest | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)atom-amd64.deb"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | sort | uniq) -O /tmp/atom-amd64.deb -q --show-progress
dpkg -i /tmp/atom-amd64.deb
```

3. Make it executable

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/atom-update`

4. Run the script to upgrade atom

`sudo atom-update`

Answer (score 1):

I would add that you should probably clean before updating the build to prevent some nasty errors.

```
cd atom
git pull
script/clean
script/build
sudo script/grunt install
```

Answer (score 0):

For debian I have created a bash script which does the following:

- Check with https://api.github.com and `dpkg` if `atom` is installed and/or up-to date.
- Download and install the atom.deb from github if needed.
- Provide a `--beta` switch if somebody wants to maintain the beta version as well.

Fell free to use it, it is located here: https://gist.github.com/rumpelsepp/8a953d6c092cbeb043695cfada114bef

Answer (score 0):

Since December 2017 Atom provides official repositories for all major Linux distributions. You can find the latest installation instructions [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#installing-atom-on-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Latest Way is to first install `$ apm install atom-updater-linux` then simply press Alt+Ctrl+U or go to Help and there is option for check for updates