# Atom: Why Linter does not highlight my errors inline with text?

Tags: plugins, atom-editor, linter, atom-plugins

I saw in tutorials that `linter` in atom must highlight html syntax errors inline with text and it also highlights lines with red bubbles near them like below:

[image]

I installed `linter-htmlhint` besides of `linter` but it did not help and currently my atom editor only reports error and do not highlight them inline with text:

[image]

What Should I do?
Here is list of my installed plugins:

- atom-html-preview
- atom-ternjs
- autoclose-html
- busy-signal
- csslint
- emmet
- htmlhint
- intentions
- language-ejs
- linter
- linter-eslint
- linter-htmlhint
- linter-jshint
- linter-ui-default
- open-in-browsers
- pigments
- Sublime-Style-Column-Selection

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with 1.26 and an upgrade of Atom made it work again.

I just followed the suggestion here: [How to upgrade Atom Editor on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741996/how-to-upgrade-atom-editor-on-linux)